# Maximum inductor current ripple in an inverter circuit

Tags: inductor, passive-filter

The following is the maximum current ripple of the system in the figure below:

[image]

In the system in the figure below, how is the maximum current ripple for L1 derived?
[image]

I know that di<sub>L</sub>/dt = DV<sub>L</sub>/(Lf<sub>sw</sub>)
this is true for a one-switching instance, assuming the switching frequency is much greater than the fundamental frequency. However, I can't see, how the above expression is developed. Any insight or guidance would be appreciated.

---

The figure and the equation are from the following paper:
"[Output Filter Design for a Grid-interconnected Three-phase Inverter](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1218154)" by Timothy CY Wang, Zhihong Ye, Gautam Sinha, Xiaoming Yuan

Comment: Please provide a clickable link to the document that the image came from

Comment: @Andyaka the post has been edited and here is the link: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1218154